# MonoGame Mediaplayer plays only one song

Tags: xna

I use:

```
    MediaPlayer.Play(song1);
```

to play a song.

Then I use

```
    MediaPlayer.Play(song2);
```

to play second song. But Mediaplayer still plays song1. I tried to stop player and play song2 again but it doesn't work. When I swap song1 and song2, it plays only song2.

Edit:
I have this class:

```
public class SoundHelper
    {
        public static void PlaySong(Song song)
        {
            MediaPlayer.Stop();
            MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        }

        public static void StopSong()
        {
            MediaPlayer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I use:

```
SoundHelper.PlaySong(Content.Load<Song>("Sounds/Songs/MenuTheme"));
```

to play song when game starts and it works.

Then I use:

```
SoundHelper.PlaySong(Content.Load<Song>("Sounds/Songs/Battle"));
```

to play next song in battle but then MenuTheme is played from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop playing current song

```
if (PlaySong1) {
     MediaPlayer.Stop();
     MediaPlayer.Play(Song1); 
}
else{
     MediaPlayer.Stop(); 
     MediaPlayer.Play(Song2); 
}
```

**EDIT**

- you code looks fine, make sure that you call "SoundHelper" only once,
  on loading menu or battle.
- also try with "try" and "catch" on MediaPlayser.Stop() not sure, but
  maybe will throw exception if no song is loaded.
- it's better to load songs in your "loadcontent" instead.

  `song1 = Content.Load<Song>("song1"); song2 = Content.Load<Song>("song2");`
- also maybe adding `MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;` could be solve.
  this is so far all i could remember.

Comment: It doesn't help. It plays song1 again

Comment: @petros please, give us a bit more code. part where you load both songs and where you try to play them.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that I'm using MonoGame. I've just checked and it works fine in clean XNA. But what can I do to make it work in MonoGame project?

Comment: @petros Try getting latest version of MonoGame. I've searched around and found they had a bug in this case. https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/pull/2946/files

Comment: Still nothing. I think I will have to use SoundEffects

Comment: not sure if mobile could handle properly this, they are handling differently background music and sound effect. there should be solution... try to dispose mediaplayer or something...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems to be a bug in MonoGame. Had that same issue.
With version 3.3 your approach should work.